# Not able to load jade block

Tags: html, node.js, pug

Here's the code:

```
//- layout.jade
doctype html
html(lang="en")
    body
        block test
```

And heres the block

```
//- test.jade
extends ./layout.jade
block test
    .foo
        | hello
```

Both jade files are in the same directory. I am compiling `index.jade` into a static file by using the jade cli.

```
$ jade layout.jade
```

The resulting layout.html file does not have the `.foo` div. There are no errors, and there **is** an html file, it just does not have the content that was in `test.jade`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are rendering test.jade, right? not layout.jade? it works fine for me with jade 1.7.0

Comment: This is not being rendered on the server. I am compiling it into a static file

Comment: ok, whatever, are you compiling test.jade or layout.jade? `jade test.jade` works fine for me

Comment: I'm compiling layout. That is the main page.

Comment: ok, well, working as intended. the point of a layout is to provide common html alongside blocks to child templates, you always render the child templates. Make an index.jade that extends layout.jade with the content you want in the block, and compile index.jade

Comment: I was looking at the [jade site](http://jade-lang.com/reference/extends/) and I noticed their example comments resemble yours. I wonder then if you were working off the same site. In that case, is the problem as simple as you forget the period slash in `extends ./layout.jade` ?

Comment: @plato, not working as intended. The jade compiler is meant to graph out all dependencies and render the file according to that graph. Either I am doing something wrong or there is a bug in this version of jade.

Comment: @ThisClark I tried this, still does not work

Comment: maybe `include test.jade` is still in recent jade versions, if so, that's what you're looking for

Comment: `include` does not allow you to encapsulate parts of a view. I am using `include` for independent widgets. But for portions of a view that are dependent on the parent layout, `block` must be used.

Comment: you've lost me. Can you edit your question to explain what and how you are compiling, and the result you expect?

Comment: @Plato done. Please tell me if it makes sense.

Comment: OK, well, i have nothing to add beyond my previous comment that you always render a template at the bottom of your extends hierarchy, and they cascade upwards; you don't render top down because there could be a dozen different templates that could fulfil the `test` block and the compiler has no idea what to put there. if neither the blocks solution or include solution work, please edit again explaining what problem you're trying to solve

Answer (score 0):

When you compile layout.jade it doesn't reference test.jade anywhere. You need to compile test.jade, whIch which extends the layout file.

Basically, test.jade extends layout.jade, despite it appearing to be the other way.